# DB Link throws ORA-28511: lost RPC connection to heterogeneous remote agent using SID

Tags: oracle, dblink

I use a DBLINK/Oracle Gateway to connect to an external non-oracle database. i have a timeout setting of 5 minutes.

when I connect using dblink, for the first time, it runs fine. After the idle time of 5 minutes, when I run the same sql again, it throws me the bellow error -
ORA-28511: lost RPC connection to heterogeneous remote agent using SID. ****
ORA-28509: unable to establish a connection to non-Oracle system
ORA-02063: preceding line from DB2T

Then when i run the sql again, its connecting fine. i guess its establishing a new connection.
Why am i getting the connection error and why oracle is not simply establishing a new connection when the previous connection is timed out?
Is there a way to not get the error and connect seamlessly or to suppress the error?

Easily replicable in sql developer by running a sql and waiting for 5 minutes.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am getting the same error, did you get a solution mate @law 
Do you know where can we alter the 5-minute timeout configuration?
For me, it's giving an error after 5 minutes even when I am continuously firing queries (via python script)